# Junits for Asynchronous calls

Tags: asynchronous, junit

How can i unit test the following code?

```
private Future<JSONArray> getData(String cqlQuery, String eventName) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    CqlClientCallable cqlClientCallable = new CqlClientCallable(cqlQuery,   
    cqlApiClient, eventName);
    Future<JSONArray> cqlResultFuture = executor.submit(cqlClientCallable);
    executor.shutdown();
    return cqlResultFuture;
```

I was trying to use Mockito in the test code like mentioned below but that returned a null since myArray is declared null(as obvious).I am not able to return a non null value using Mockito.

```
        Future<JSONArray> myArray = null;
    Mockito.when(executor.submit(cqlClientCallable)).thenReturn(myArray);
```

Comment: Inject the ExecutorService into the class instead of creating it inside the getData mrthod. Injected properties can be mocked easily

Comment: I cannot change the main code.Need a work around with the existing code.Any idea how can i assign some value to myArray?

Comment: there is no other way. you have to change it..  refer this url
http://www.alexecollins.com/5-tips-unit-testing-threaded-code/